# How to construct a match expression

Tags: parsing, command-line, f#, pattern-matching

I am allowing a command-line parameter like this `--10GB`, where `--` and `GB` are constant, but a number like 1, 10, or 100 could be substituted in between the constant values, like `--5GB`.

I could easily parse the start and end of the string with `substr` or written a command line parser, but wanted to use `match` instead. I am just not sure how to structure the match expression.

```
let GB1     = cvt_bytes_to_gb(int64(DiskFreeLevels.GB1))
let arg = argv.[0]

let match_head = "--"
let match_tail  = "GB"

let parse_min_gb_arg arg =
    match arg with
    | match_head & match_tail -> cvt_gb_arg_to_int arg
    | _ -> volLib.GB1
```

I get a warning saying `_ This rule will never be matched.` How should the what is an AND expression be constructed?

Comment: Just use regular expressions! (I never thought I'd get to say this one ;))

Comment: If the GB is a constant it feels a bit superflous to specify it but with all due respect, why don't you just use a command line parsing library like [Argu](http://fsprojects.github.io/Argu/) or [CommandLine](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline), both are very good.

Comment: @s952163 I agree with your suggestion to parse more formally for a more formal application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't match on strings, except matching on the whole value, e.g. `match s with  | "1" -> 1 | "2" -> 2 ...`

Parsing beginning and end would be the most efficient way to do this, there is no need to get clever (this, by the way, is a universally true statement).

But if you *really* want to use pattern matching, it is definitely possible to do, but you'll have to make yourself some custom matchers (also known as "active patterns").

First, make a custom matcher that would parse out the "middle" part of the string surrounded by prefix and suffix:

```
let (|StrBetween|_|) starts ends (str: string) =
  if str.StartsWith starts && str.EndsWith ends then 
    Some (str.Substring(starts.Length, str.Length - ends.Length - starts.Length))
  else 
    None
```

Usage:

```
let x = match "abcd" with 
        | StrBetween "a" "d" s -> s
        | _ -> "nope"
// x = "bc"
```

Then make a custom matcher that would parse out an integer:

```
let (|Int|_|) (s: string) = 
    match System.Int32.TryParse s with 
    | true, i -> Some i 
    | _ -> None
```

Usage:

```
let x = match "15" with 
        | Int i -> i
        | _ -> 0
// x = 15
```

Now, combine the two:

```
let x = match "--10GB" with 
        | StrBetween "--" "GB" (Int i) -> i 
        | _ -> volLib.GB1
// x = 10
```

This ability of patterns to combine and nest is their primary power: you get to build a complicated pattern out of small, easily understandable pieces, and have the compiler match it to the input. That's basically why it's called "*pattern matching*". :-)

Comment: Nobody ever considers [string slice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/strings) syntax. `Some str.[starts.Length .. str.Length - ends.Length - 1]`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big fan of it.

Answer (score 4):

The best I can come up with is using a partial active pattern:

```
let (|GbFormat|_|) (x:string) =
    let prefix = "--"
    let suffix  = "GB"
    if x.StartsWith(prefix) && x.EndsWith(suffix) then
        let len = x.Length - prefix.Length - suffix.Length
        Some(x.Substring(prefix.Length, len))
    else
        None

let parse_min_gb_arg arg =
    match arg with
    | GbFormat gb -> gb
    | _ -> volLib.GB1

parse_min_gb_arg "--42GB"
```

Comment: You're kind of defeating the whole point of active patterns: there is no pattern, it's just a function call. Could just as well be a function and used like `match gbFormat arg with | Some gb -> gb | None -> volLib.GB1`.

Comment: Yep, you predicated it with "if you really want", I predicated it with "best I can come up with", we are saying the same thing.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my comment. I was trying to say that if you're going to use patterns, you should make small ones and combine them, rather than making a big one that does everything in one go. This is a good strategy with ordinary functions, too.

Comment: Ah, I take your point. There's no point baking the values in, otherwise you aren't composing the usage of it, or being descriptive in the match statement.